# How to create object id:name format in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Currently in my application, I have some data contains id and name.

```
data = [
  {id: 1, name: 'user 1'}, 
  {id: 2 , name: 'user 2'}
]
```

I want to display in id:name format

```
{id: "name", id: "name" ....}
{1 : "user 1" , 2: "user 2" ...}
```

Comment: You could make a 2-Dimensional array where `data[0][0]` will be the id of the first user, while `data[0][1]` is their name. Otherwise, you can use maps where the users `id` is the key to their `name`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to change that array of objects the way you want to, I would probably do it as follows:

```js
let obj = {};
data.map(e => {
  obj[e.id] = e.name;
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This will result in the array `[{1: user 1}, {2: user 2}, ...]`. While similar, not quite what the question requested.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, thought misread. it doesn't change much, it's even easier. `let obj = {};
data.map(e => {
  obj[e.id] = e.name;
});` I edited my original reply

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` to create the object this way

```js
const array = [
 {id : 1,name : "user 1"}, {id :2 , name : "user 2"}
];
const object = array.reduce((o, s) => { 
   o[s.id] = s.name;
   return o;
}, {});
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through your data and transform it into a new object. This is how I would do it so the key is the id like your example and the value is the name. and if you want more properties set to the key you could even just set it to person instead of person.name.

```
data.reduce((hash, person) => {
  return hash[person.id] = person.name
}, {})
```

Here are the docs for the [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).